# gin gonic bind multiple params (query + json)

Tags: go, go-gin

Is there a way in gin gonic to combine bindings cleanly, or something like a BindAll. In my case I have both query and json parameters, so Bind/BindJSON and BindQuery.
If I understand it right up to here the bindings have to be used one after the other, which makes the code confusing. Unfortunately, even after a lot of googling I didn't find anything reasonable (the examples were simply limited to one type). Example:

```
type Params struct {
  Userid string `form:"user_id" json:"user_id" query:"user_id" binding:"required"`
  Password string `json:"password" binding:"required"`
}


func Create(c *gin.Context) {
  var params Params

    if err := c.ShouldBind(&params); err == nil {
        log.Println("GOOD1")
        log.Println(params)
    } else {
        log.Println("ERROR1")
        log.Println(params)
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
    }

    if err := c.ShouldBindQuery(&params); err == nil {
        log.Println("GOOD2")
        log.Println(params)
    } else {
        log.Println("ERROR2")
        log.Println(params)
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
    }

}
```

Call:

```
curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:8080/v1/receipt?user_id=123 -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"login":"my_login","password":"my_password"}'
```

Expecting something like this:

```
if err := c.ShouldBindAll(&params); err == nil {
    log.Println("GOOD1")
    log.Println(params)
} else {
    log.Println("ERROR1")
    log.Println(params)
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
}
```

Comment: There isn't a builtin way, you may implement your own binding. However, what happens when a client sends the same parameter in multiple ways, e.g. both as form and json? Which one takes precedence?

Comment: Also query binding is done with `form` struct tags. The `query` tag doesn't exist. Gin binds from query params or request body binding based on http method and content type

Comment: @blackgreen Thank you very much for your quick reply. I am quite new to golang. So it is best practice in golang/gin gonic to handle the parameters in each "controller" function individually?

Comment: Handling arbitrary bindings is surely uncommon. The thing is, does your client **actually** send parameters *to the same endpoint* with *the same HTTP method* in multiple ways? I would expect that queries are sent with GET, and post form or json with POST. In that case you can easily set up different handlers

Answer (score -1):

```golang
  // If `GET`, only `Form` binding engine (`query`) used.
  // If `POST`, first checks the `content-type` for `JSON` or `XML`, then uses `Form` (`form-data`).
  // See more at https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/binding/binding.go#L48
  if c.ShouldBind(&person) == nil {
```

gin can't do 'combine bindings', 'content-type' will tell it how to bind datas. I you want parse the query parameters correctly, you can't use `c.Query` to get `user_id` parameter.

```golang
var params Params

if err := c.ShouldBind(&params); err == nil {
   log.Println("GOOD1")
   params.UserId = c.Query("user_id")
   log.Println(params)
} else {
   log.Println("ERROR1")
   log.Println(params)
   c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
}
```